# Using LiteIDE and Google App Engine - Folder Structure

Tags: go, liteide

I have a tool, call it *mytool*, that makes use of other code in a separate package I have written - call it *mypackage*.

I can build and test it in LiteIDE if I use the following structure:

```
/src/mypackage/mypackage.go
/src/mytool/tool.go
/src/mytool/tool.yaml
```

but when I want to test or deploy on GAE using:

```
cd ... \src\
\go\gae\go_appengine\dev_appserver.py mytool/
```

or

```
\go\gae\go_appengine\appcfg.py update mytool/
```

I have to move stuff around to:

```
/src/mytool/mypackage/mypackage.go
/src/mytool/tool.go
/src/mytool/tool.yaml
```

Is there something I can change in LteIDE so it can handle the second structure or is there something I can change in the GAE setup to make it handle the first structure?

I am working on Windows 7.

Comment: For the time being I have created a symlink for the package folder so it seems to be in two places at once but I would welcome a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the package using `go install`?

That creates the compiled binary in the packages directory so the rest of your packages/code can treat it the same as a 3rd-party package.

Comment: No I haven't - I am working on the package as well as the tool so having to remember to reinstall the package every time I change it would be annoying.